# Node.js: Email data as attachment without saving it

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, email-attachments

I have an app on Heroku which creates a .CSV file depending on some user input and emails it ot the user.

As Heroku is a read-only service (which I just found out) I can't actually save the file in the Heroky file system.

I'm wondering if I can send an email with the .csv as an attachment without saving it?!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [node-mailer](https://github.com/andris9/Nodemailer#attachment-fields) module to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has [add-ons](https://addons.heroku.com/) for various types of databases if you are wanting to save the data, and their [dev-center](https://devcenter.heroku.com/) has a lot of documentation on how to wire them up.

If you are not sending mail directly from the server, there is a [node module](https://npmjs.org/package/mailgun-js) for [Mailgun](http://www.mailgun.com/), which will let you send mail (with attachments) via API.